# The radius of earth is 3,960 miles, it spins one full revolution every 24 hours. Find how fast a city spins 40 degrees north.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I did find the answer to my question here; [Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3817653/how-fast-are-you-moving-on-the-earth-at-a-given-latitude/3817868#3817868)

Before I found the answer, I didn't know much about the cos function.  I was trying to subtract the arc length out of the circumference and use what was left of the circumference as the distance the city 40 degrees north would have to travel in 24 hours. The city had to travel 320 degrees around in 24 hours.  I end up with 921mph. I was doing this because the chapter I am reading didn't say anything about cos.  I was wondering if a sphere has some property for finding a radius of a point on the surface of the object that doesn't involve using cos.

Here is the answer using cos $$\frac{3,960 \space * \space 2\pi \space *\space cos(\frac{2\pi}{9})miles}{24 hours}= 794 mph$$

A sphere is round.  It seems like 40 degrees north or east is still 40 degrees. It must have something to do with locating the city and then finding how fast it is spinning?  I am not sure why the answers are so different.  921 mph is much faster than 794 mph.

Comment: Earth is not a sphere.

Comment: I bet I read that somewhere that it was ok to assume a sphere and didn't question that.  thanks

Comment: It looks like you're getting $320$ as $360-40$ -- but how on earth (ahem!) did you get the idea to do that, and by which reasoning would it be the right thing to do? If you could do something like that, wouldn't you also conclude that the north pole (at latitude $90^\circ$ north) moves by $270^\circ$ a day, rather than being immobile?

Comment: The city travels 360 degrees per day regardless of its latitude. 360 degrees is one full circle. At latitude 40 the city traverses a different circle than a city on the equator. A degree is not a distance.

Comment: I did not know how to use Cosine to find the radius.  I thought maybe I could do so by subtracting arc length. I wonder what would happen if you took pi out too?

Comment: "subtracting arc length" ... "if you took pi out too" ... These techniques don't seem to have any reasons behind them; it's almost like randomly stringing words from the problem together (with just a few constraints of grammar). It's a good time to start considering what makes a *reason* for an answer as opposed to just that a formula happens to give answers your professors approve.

Comment: If I am looking for a city 40 degrees north I can use arc length to locate that city on the surface of the earth. The equation for arc length is $s=\theta*r$ If the earth has a radius of 3,980 miles, a city 40 degrees north is $s=3,980*\frac{2\pi}{9}radians$. The city is 2,764.601535 miles north.  Also the circumference around the earth is $2\pi*3960$.  To find the speed of the earth then of a city 40 deg N, I used this formula.  $\frac{\pi*3,960-2,764.601535}{12h}$. The answer here is 806 mph.  The book says 794 mph.  I wasn’t sure if there was a formula that could estimate mph without cos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any spinning circle on earth rotates $360^\circ$ in $24$ hours.

A spinning radius $40^\circ$ north, the
[Nebraska/Kansas border](https://www.washburn.edu/cas/art/cyoho/archive/KStravel/fallbreak2001/40thparallel.html),
is

$$3960\cdot \cos{\dfrac{40\pi}{180}}
=3033.54\space mi$$

The speed of rotation is

$$\dfrac{2\pi(3033.54\space mi)}{24h}
 =794.18\space mph = 1278.63 \space kph$$

Answer (score -1):

Seems alright. Since in general if $ {\theta} $ is latitude,

$$r=R\cos \theta, \omega = \frac{2 \pi}{24};$$

$$V_{along \;a \;parallel \; circle} = \omega \cdot r \text { miles/hour}$$.

Comment: How can I improve the answer?